# How to call several functions, so they will wait each other in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 3 functions and one button. I want to press the button and call `3 function` not at the same time, but one after another, so each function waits till another (previous function) is completed

I have a `onPost,` `onGet` and `navigate` function
What I would like to do ist to call a function `allTogether`

```
allTogether() {

 this.onPost();
 this.onGet();
 this.navigate();

}
```

Here is my `onPost` Method, where I send data of current client to backend

```
 onPost () {
    const messageForDb = (JSON.stringify(this.model));
    localStorage.setItem('userKey', messageForDb);
    this._httpService.postJSON(this.model)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.postData = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => alert(error),
      );
  }
```

Here is my `onGet()` and here I get information about my client, so I can use it later in third function `navigation()`

```
  onGet() {
        this._httpService.getCurrentState(this.model.user_email, this.model.client)
      .subscribe(
       // data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
        data => this.getData = data,
        error => alert(error),
      );
  }

navigation () {
  let  part = json.message.part;
  let  num = json.message.number;
  this.router.navigate(['part'], {queryParams: {'number': 'num'}});
}
```

I tried with subscribe, but failed...so how cloud I implements the function `allTogether()` else ? I tested all functions and they work separately, but all together..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the next method from the part of the subscribe function that assigns the data.

```
onPost () {
    const messageForDb = (JSON.stringify(this.model));
    localStorage.setItem('userKey', messageForDb);
    this._httpService.postJSON(this.model)
      .subscribe(
           data => { this.postData = JSON.stringify(data); this.onGet();},
           error => alert(error),
  );
}

onGet() {
    this._httpService.getCurrentState(this.model.user_email, 
    this.model.client)
      .subscribe(
       // data => { this.getData = JSON.stringify(data); this.navigate(); },
        data => { this.getData = data; this.navigate(); },
        error => alert(error),
  );
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Observable.forkJoin` operator to make the third function wait for the results of the first 2. I see the data between them is not dependent on each other. You also have to modify `onPost` and `onGet` so they return `observables`.

```
onPost () {
    const messageForDb = (JSON.stringify(this.model));
    localStorage.setItem('userKey', messageForDb);
    return this._httpService.postJSON(this.model);
 }

onGet() {
        return this._httpService.getCurrentState(this.model.user_email, this.model.client);
  }

Observable.forkJoin([this.onPost(), this.onGet()])
   .subscribe((resultArray) => {
     [postResult, getResult] = resultArray;
     this.postData = JSON.stringify(postResult);
     this.getData = getResult;
     this.navigation();
   });
```